# How can I display value in table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to edit a open-source project which I downloaded from internet 
I want to display the value of HSN no. in table,here is the code.

```
var $hsn;
$("#invoice_item").delegate(".product_name","change",function(){
var pid = $(this).val();
var tr = $(this).parent().parent();

if (pid != 0) {
  $.ajax({
    url : domain+"/includes/update.php",
    method : "POST",
    data : {get_price_qty:1,pid:pid},
    success : function(data){
      if(data == "NO_PRODUCT"){
        alert("Sorry, Selected product is not available");
      }else{
        var ar = data.split(",");

        tr.find(".pro_name").val(ar[2]);
        tr.find(".price").val(ar[0]);
        tr.find(".total_qty").val(ar[1]);
        tr.find(".qty").val(0);
        tr.find(".hsn").val(ar[3]);
        tr.find(".amt").html(tr.find(".price").val() * tr.find(".qty").val());
        $hsn=ar[3];
        $("#discount").val(0);
      }
    }
  })
}else{
  alert("Please Select at least one product");
} })
```

Here is how the table looks
[image: Table]

Now the code for adding a new row is as below

```
if (isset($_POST["addNewRow"])) {
 $num = $_POST["number"];
 $pro = new DBOperation();
 $rows = $pro->displayBrandAndCategory("products");
 ?>
 <tr>
    <td><b class="number"></b></td>
    <td>
    <select name="pname[]" class="form-control form-control-sm product_name">
    <option value="0">Choose Product</option>
 <?php
 foreach ($rows as $row) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['pro_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row["pro_name"]; ?></option>
    <?php
 }
 ?>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><input name="total_qty[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm total_qty" readonly></td>
    <td><input name="qty[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm qty"></td>
    <td><input name="hsn[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm qty" readonly> </td>
    <td><input name="price[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm price" readonly></td>
    <td>Rs.<span class="amt">0</span></td>
  </tr>
 <?php
 exit();}
```

but hsn column is always showing 0,I tried doing this

```
document.write(ar[3]);
```

It correctly shows the HSN no. I don't know exactly what the statement below does,could anyone explain it to me?

```
tr.find(".hsn").val(ar[3]);
```

Comment: I don't see any HTML element with a class called "hsn". So `tr.find(".hsn")` won't find any elements on the page. The "." in a CSS selector like that means it's looking for a class. Were you trying to look for the element with "hsn" as the "name" attribute?

Comment: I got the answer for my problem I needed to change <td><input name="hsn[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm qty" readonly> </td> to <td><input name="hsn[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm hsn" readonly> </td>  @ADyson you are right  there was no class named hsn in there